# Neo4j from JavaScript login info

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

For the code below how do I get the username and password.  From  [enter link description here](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/)

```
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "123456"));
var session = driver.session();
```

Is it my ID when I login?

[image]

or is it the database name and password?

[image]

I tried both ways still having trouble.

Comment: I think the default is neo4j:neo4j... login into web browser and it will ask you to change your password

Answer (score 1):

It's the latter, but the database name doesn't play a part here.

The database name in this case is only for your own reference within the Neo4j Desktop app.

The default database user is `neo4j`, and the app forces you to choose the password when you create the database, so you should know the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable authentication. Just uncomment `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in config file. So you will not have problems with authentication. The default username and password are neo4j:neo4j